# Как сделать чтобы в поле mongodb приходил либо пустой массив, либо уникальная строка

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть такая модель:

```
import {Schema, model} from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    warranty: {type: Number, required: true},
    serial: [
        { type: String,  unique: true, required: true },
    ],
})

export default model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

Хочу такую реализацию:

1. Если поле serial пустое, то надо чтобы я мог добавляить сколь угодно таких записей.

   {
   "product": {
   name: "hp pavilion1",
   warranty: 1,
   serial: []
   }
   }
2. Если поле serial не пустое, то надо чтобы прилетали строки и они должны быть уникальные, то есть если есть запись с масивом serial, то в нём дожны быть строки уникальны и чтобы в других записях я не мог добавить такие же значения как и в предедущих.

   {
   "product": {
   name: "hp pavilion",
   warranty: 1,
   serial: [
   "0EG118439X",
   "4UY113239E"
   ]
   }
   }

Как мне это реализовать?

В первом случае у меня создаёться одна запись, а дальше, если я хочу поле serial оставить пустым у меня вылетает ошибка: MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.products index: serial_1 dup key: { serial: undefined }